# Is there a way of supporting Interfaces in AspNet WebAPI Controller Actions other than using MediaTypeFormatters?

Tags: interface, asp.net-web-api

I need to know if there is a way to support interfaces in AspNet WebAPI other than using MediaTypeFormatters?

Comment: You need to be more specific about where you want to use interfaces?

Comment: I am surprised to hear this from you Darrel. Controller actions can result instances of concrete classes. What if we want controller actions to return interfaces? I hope now you have clear understanding of what I am asking.

Comment: You need to find a serializer that can support serializing interfaces.    Serializing interfaces is a bit of a contradiction though.  Serialization usually assumes you are going to deserialize and there is no way a serializer can deserialize an interface without more information.  Also, I have no idea why you would want to create controller actions that expose interfaces.  It makes no sense to me.

Comment: The controller class accesses data using a IRepository which in turn knows about IEntity. Only the concrete repository knows about concrete entities. Any method of IRepository would return IEntity. Now either I've to manually convert IEntity to Entity within the controller, or made controller to return IEntity. Don't like to bind IRepository with concrete Entity type.

Comment: For reference, you can take a look at another question that I've posted here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266518/mediatypeformatter-issue-in-self-hosted-aspnet-webapi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your above comments, are you looking for content-negotiation to happen on the instance type rather than the declared return type of your action? By default, Web API uses the declared return type to do content negotiation.

If yes, currently we do not have a clean way to achieve this, but following is one workaround you could use:

Example:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetEntity()
{
    IEntity derivedEntityInstance = new Person()
    {
        Id = 10,
        Name = "Mike",
        City = "Redmond"
    };

    IContentNegotiator negotiator = this.Configuration.Services.GetContentNegotiator();
    ContentNegotiationResult negotiationResult = negotiator.Negotiate(derivedEntityInstance.GetType(), this.Request, this.Configuration.Formatters);

    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new ObjectContent(derivedEntityInstance.GetType(), derivedEntityInstance, negotiationResult.Formatter);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = negotiationResult.MediaType;

    return response;
}
```

**NOTE**: In the soon to come release, we are providing an easy way to achieve this.

**EDIT**:
Based on your comment, following is an example. The release which I was talking about is already out. You can upgrade your packages to the `5.0.0-beta2` version. After this you could like the following:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetEntity()
{
       IEntity derivedEntityInstance = new Person()
       {
           Id = 10,
           Name = "Mike",
           City = "Redmond"
       };

       // 'Content' method actually creates something called 'NegotiatedContentResult'
       // which handles with content-negotiating your response.
       // Here if you had specified 'return Content<BaseEntityType>(HttpStatusCode.OK, derivedEntityInstance)', then the content-negotiation would have occurred based on your 'BaseEntityType', otherwise if you do like below, it would try to get the type out of the derivedEntityInstance and does con-neg on it.
       return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, derivedEntityInstance);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was really useful Kiran. Would you please let me know when the new release is expected that cleanly handles the aforementioned scenario?

Comment: @ImranNazir: I made the edit to the above post with how you can do with the latest code. Let me know how it goes!...thanks..